# Cannot access controller method when using app.UseSpa .Net 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I upgraded my .net core application from 2.1 to .NET 6. I left most of my code the same, apart from moving my startup code to the program class.

The problem I am experiencing is that I cannot access my controller endpoints when I have the app.UseSpa in my pipeline. It keeps redirecting to the Angular site regardless of the url I type int. I have tried moving things around in the pipeline, but still nothing. I thought that because it is being called last in the pipeline, it should first look for the controllers and then when that is not found it should redirect to the SPA static file location.

When I remove the app.UseSpa I am able to reach my controllers.

Here is my code:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
        
        AddServicesToContainer(builder);

        var app = builder.Build();
        
        ConfigurePipeline(app);
        
        app.Run();
    }

    private static void ConfigurePipeline(WebApplication app)
    {
        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        
        app.UseSpaStaticFiles();
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseHangfireServer();
        app.UseHangfireDashboard();
        
        app.MapControllerRoute(
            name: "default",
            pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        

        RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate<UpdateStoresService>("UpdateStoresJob", service => service.UpdateStores(), "0 7-19 * * *",
            TimeZoneInfo.Local);

        app.UseSpa(spa =>
        {
            spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
        
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                spa.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
            }
        });
    }

    private static void AddServicesToContainer(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
                cfg.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                cfg.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                cfg.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                cfg.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<CRMContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddCookie()
            .AddJwtBearer(cfg =>
            {
                var tokenOptions = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(TokensOptions)).Get<TokensOptions>();
                cfg.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidIssuer = tokenOptions.Issuer,
                    ValidAudience = tokenOptions.Audience,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(tokenOptions.Key))
                };
            });

        var connectionStrings = builder.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(ConnectionStrings)).Get<ConnectionStrings>();

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<CRMContext>(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.UseSqlServer(
                connectionStrings.CRMConnectionString,
                sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(60));
        });

        builder.Services.AddDbContext<StoresMasterListContext>(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.UseSqlServer(
                connectionStrings.StoresMasterListConnectionString,
                sqlServerOptions => sqlServerOptions.CommandTimeout(60));
        });

        builder.Services.AddAutoMapper();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ICRMRepository, CRMRepository>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IStoresMasterListRepository, StoresMasterListRepository>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ILookup, Lookup>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IZalisa, Zalisa>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IAAMembership, AAMembership>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<CRMDataSeeder>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IEmailService, EmailService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<IGoogleReviews, GoogleReviews>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ISMS, SMS>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ISpecSavers, SpecSavers>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ICalicoQuotesService, CalicoQuotesService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<ICalicoCloudAppointmentService, CalicoCloudAppointmentService>();
        builder.Services.AddScoped<UpdateStoresService>();
        
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
        
        builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
        {
            configuration.RootPath = ("ClientApp/dist");
        });
        
        InjectOptions(builder);
        
        try
        {
            builder.Services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(connectionStrings.CRMConnectionString));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

        }
    }

    private static void InjectOptions(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        var allTypes = Assembly.Load("KFML.CRM.Shared").GetTypes();

        var types = allTypes
            .Where(t => typeof(ICrmOption).IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.IsClass && !t.IsAbstract)
            .ToList();

        var configureMethod = typeof(OptionsConfigurationServiceCollectionExtensions).GetMethods().First();

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            var genericMethod = configureMethod.MakeGenericMethod(type);
            genericMethod.Invoke(builder.Services,
                new object[] {builder.Services, builder.Configuration.GetSection(type.Name)});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How about using `app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");`  instead of `app.UseSpa();` Like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyMdG.png

Comment: would that not just go to an index page in the wwwRoot folder? And also I want it to start my angular CLI in development. I know I can probably move my angular application to the wwwRoot and then I don't have to use SpaStaticFiles or app.UseSPA, but I really would like to know why it is not working as expected.

Comment: Hi Mervyn Ludick, could you please kindly check the official link: [Document migration process for SPA projects](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/44600)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because the Angular wants to handle all routes. So you need to say to your middleware that you want to `UseSpa` only on Angular routes. You can do it like this (with explaining comments):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var services = builder.Services;

services.AddControllers();

if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
{
    services.AddSpaStaticFiles(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist/ClientApp";
    });
}

var app = builder.Build();

app.MapControllers();

// Run middleware when request is sent to endpoint which should be handled by Angular, so for example all except API endpoints
var excludedPaths = new PathString[] { "/api" };
app.UseWhen((ctx) =>
{
    var path = ctx.Request.Path;
    return !Array.Exists(excludedPaths, excluded => path.StartsWithSegments(excluded, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
}, then =>
{
    // Use static files from Angular dist folder in production
    if (builder.Environment.IsProduction())
    {
        then.UseSpaStaticFiles();
    }

    then.UseSpa(cfg =>
    {
        // While development we want to start Angular app
        if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
            cfg.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";
            cfg.UseAngularCliServer("start");
        }
    });
});

app.Run();
```

Comment: Nice thinking, but I would actually prefer if the angular middleware doesn't get reached in the pipeline if there was a matching request.

Comment: Maybe the `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints=>endpoints.MapControllers())` before `app.UseSpa()` will work? I cant test it now

Comment: I ended up adding app.UseEndpoints(_ => { }); just before app.UseSpa();. I think it will have the same effect that you commented. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does not work for me, is there any way to debug this? Even breakpoint is not being hit within the condition.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal, you mean that `!Array.Exists(...)` is never executed?

Comment: @Szyszka947 sometimes it is, sometimes it is not, really confused here. adding `logger.LogCritical(context.Request.Path.Value) ;` to `app.UseWhen` produces nothing in Kestrel output window.

Comment: I think something may be wrong with your middleware setup, maybe open a new question with your `Program.cs`